# My divs are overlapping, i'm lost

Tags: html, css

Hey I can't figure out why my divs are overlapping and what i should do...

You can watch the site here: http://hersing.dk/job/

I would like for the div carrying the hr to appear underneed the header-info div

Heres is the code from the site:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: hersing;
  src: url(lmroman10-regular.otf);
}
html,
body {
  font-family: hersing;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.info-name {
  left: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.info-picture {
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 5%;
  background: black;
  display: block;
}
.info-picture img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#info-header {
  font-size: 400%;
}
#info-title {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.header-info {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.stang-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
}
#hr-1 {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1a857;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-info">
    <div class="info-name" id="info-name">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="info-picture" id="info-picture">
      <img src="images/picture.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stang-1" id="stang-1">
    <hr id="hr-1">
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope someome can figure this out, cause i'm pretty lost

Comment: Absolute positioning is a very inflexible layout method. There are much better options available to you. See [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-info">
    <div class="info-name" id="info-name">
          ..... 
    </div>
    <div class="info-picture" id="info-picture">
      <img src="images/picture.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stang-1" id="stang-1">
     <hr id="hr-1">
  </div>
</div>


    <style>
@font-face {
  font-family: hersing;
  src: url(lmroman10-regular.otf);
}
html,
body {
  font-family: hersing;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.info-name {
  left: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.info-picture {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left:70%;
  background: black;
  display: block;
}
.info-picture img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#info-header {
  font-size: 400%;
}
#info-title {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.header-info {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.stang-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
#hr-1 {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1a857;
}
</style>
```

I think this will solve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Both `.info-name` and `.info-picture` are `absolute` positioned and `.header-info` has no `height` defined.

You'd rather use `relative` positioning + `float` + `clear` and/or `display: inline-block` for both `.info-*` rules and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, although very impractical, the solution would be to add a line break `<br>` after the `.header-info` div.

I repeat, this solution is not the best one by far, and you should, as pointed out in the comments by Paulie_D, change your positioning layout method.

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the absolutely positioned `.container` would be better positioned `relative`. Use css `float:left;` or `float:right;` to position elements and `clear:both;` when you want the next element to start below all floated elements. Use `padding` on the container and margins on the floated elements for positioning.

Also give `.container` css class of `overflow:auto;` to wrap around all elements inside without having to set the `height` every time.